# Environment for run Visual C++ 6.0 application

Tags: visual-c++, frameworks, exe

I am having a `.exe` file, that is created in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 environment. I want to run that `exe`, when i click on it, it's showing error dialog. What is the environment i need to run that `exe`. Is it any framework we need to run that one?

Comment: and what is the error you are getting

Comment: the error shows "it's not valid to execute". but if i install visual c++ 6.0 software then no problem that exe execute well. I want to run that exe without visual C++ 6.0 software